# Datagridview coloring cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, colors, cell

I'm experiencing a problem with the `datagridview`. I'm trying to create a program that allows me to run certain tests. I want to list them in a `datagridview`. Then with a counter I want the program to go through the active serverprocesses and run them. In the overview I want to visualize whether a process is active by coloring a cell that i add. I've done this before and used the same code but this time it doesn't seem to work. You can find my code for the `load` event of the form here. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 Private Sub frmServerProcesses_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim oDR As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing

    'bij het opstarten moet de stopknop disabled zijn
    btnServerStop.Enabled = False
    btnServerStart.Enabled = True

    statServerProcesseslbl.Text = "Server ready"

    'opvragen van de processen
    strSQL = " SELECT * FROM SERVERPROCESSES"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectstring)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "SERVERPROCESSES")
    connection.Close()

    dgvServerProcesses.DataSource = ds
    dgvServerProcesses.DataMember = "SERVERPROCESSES"
    dgvServerProcesses.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    dgvServerProcesses.Columns("LASTRUNDATE").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    'lege row die normaal wordt toegevoegd verwijderen
    dgvServerProcesses.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    'extra kolom toevoegen voor kleuren van actief of niet
    dgvServerProcesses.Columns.Add("TEST", "TEST")

    For i As Integer = 1 To dgvServerProcesses.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvServerProcesses.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "True" Then

            dgvServerProcesses.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Black
        End If
    Next

    'lege row die normaal wordt toegevoegd verwijderen
    dgvServerProcesses.AllowUserToAddRows = False

End Sub
```

I've just tried to put both things in separate subs. So filling up the grid and marking the active ones are separate now. Both subs are called by the `load` sub. But still the colors don't work. But if I call the `checkprocess` with a button it does work. But what is also very strange is that the columncount is different. If I call it with a button he starts counting on 1 in the other case on 0. Can someone explain that to me? My new code to check the active boolean is shown here

```
Public Sub CheckProcessActive()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvServerProcesses.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvServerProcesses.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = "True" Then
            dgvServerProcesses.Rows(i).Cells("ACTIVE").Style.BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            dgvServerProcesses.Rows(i).Cells("ACTIVE").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you have noticed is *normal*. Even if you set the `DataSource` property, the `DatagridView` won't create columns and be populated until the grid is displayed, it's not populated immediately after setting this property.

You can use the [DataGridView.DataBindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) event to be sure the grid is populated when you change the style and call `CheckProcessActive()` here.